# Spring Boot - Property placeholders remain unresolved despite setting values with System.setProperty

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a bean with a constructor as follows. The `password` argument is resolved from the placeholder `my.password`, with a default value of `DEFAULT`. If the value of `DEFAULT` is passed, a warning is logged. Note - this Bean is contained within an imported third-party library.

```
@Bean
public class EncryptionBean {
    public EncryptionBean(@Value("${my.password}") String password) {
        if "DEFAULT".equals(password) {
            // log warning message
        } else {
            // do stuff with the password
        }

    }
}
```

The password is retrieved at startup from an external system using a client SDK. This SDK object is itself provided as a Bean (also from a third-party library). After retrieving the password, I am setting it as a System property for the above `EncryptionBean` to have access to at the time of instantiation:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    public SDKObject sdkObject;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.setProperty("my.password", sdkObject.retrievePassword());

        // @Value("${my.password"}) should now be resolvable when EncryptionBean is instantiated
    }

}
```

However, `EncryptionBean` is still being instantiated with a value of `DEFAULT` for `my.password`.  I'm wondering if `System.setProperty` in `@PostConstruct` might be getting executed AFTER Spring has already instantiated the instance of `EncryptionBean`?

If so, is there a way to guarantee this property has been set before Spring instantiates `EncryptionBean`? I came across `@DependsOn` as a way to control the order Beans get instantiated by Spring, but since `EncryptionBean` comes from a third-party library, I haven't been able to make this annotation work.

Answer (score 0):

I could not figure out a nice clean way to inject a property at runtime without a lot of boilerplate. But I came up with a clean way to do what you want to do without having to refresh the application context or messing with the 3rd party library implementation.

First we exclude the 3rd party bean from our application context:

```java
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(value = EncryptionBean.class, type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE))
@SpringBootApplication
public class SandboxApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SandboxApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Then we create the Bean ourselves with the values we want.

```java
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    public final SDKObject sdkObject;

    public MyConfiguration(SDKObject sdkObject) {
        this.sdkObject = sdkObject;
    }

    @Bean
    public EncryptionBean encryptionBean() {
        return new EncryptionBean(sdkObject.retrievePassword());
    }

}
```

Comment: It is not true that `@Value` only loads properties from `application.properties`. Values can be loaded from any of the sources that are backed by the Spring Environment abstraction, as listed in the Spring Boot documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config. This list includes system properties.

Comment: Edited my answer to remove that line.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting a system property, you should create a Spring `EnvironmentPostProcessor` class to retrieve the password from the external source and add it to the Spring `Environment`. That would look something like this:

```
public class PasswordEnvironmentPostProcessor implements EnvironmentPostProcessor, ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void postProcessEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment environment, SpringApplication application) {
        SDKObject sdkObject = applicationContext.getBean(SDKObject.class);
        Map<String, Object> properties = Collections.singletonMap("my.password", sdkObject.retrievePassword());
        MapPropertySource propertySource = new MapPropertySource("password", properties);
        environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(propertySource);
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

Then you'll need to register this class with Spring by adding an entry to the file `META-INF/spring.factories` that looks like this:

```
org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor=com.example.PaswordEnvironmentPostProcessor
```

Documentation for this is available here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.application.customize-the-environment-or-application-context.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer and linking documentation! This leads me to a follow up question (which highlights gaps in my understanding of how/when Spring Boot instantiates beans and resolves properties). When you retrieve the SDKObject bean from the application context, wouldn't the EncryptionBean ALSO be available at this point? Meaning its constructor had already been called and passed in values resolved from the placeholder ${my.password} , making it too late to resolve the values from the property source we have added?